# Aggregate by one variable but adding other variables

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

I have a `data.frame` with this structure:

```
id time var1 var2 var3
1     2    4    5    6
1     4    8   51    7
1     1    9   17   38
2    12    8    9   21
2    15   25    6   23
```

For all the ids, I want to have the row that contains the minimum time. In the example in would be this:

```
id time var1 var2 var3   
1     1    9   17   38
2    12    8    9   21
```

I think that the `aggregate` function would be useful, but I'm not sure how to use it.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example

Comment: Do you have a tie-breaker? Or is one minimum value guaranteed?

Answer (score 1):

Your title may be misleading, since you really just want to keep the row with the minimum `time` for every `id`. Try this:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    arrange(id, time) %>%
    filter(row_number() == 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use [`by`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/by.html), [`do.call`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/do.call.html), and the ever useful [`which.min`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/which.min.html) function to get what we need:

```
do.call('rbind', by(df, df$id, function(x) x[which.min(x$time), ]))

#   id time var1 var2 var3
# 1  1    1    9   17   38
# 2  2   12    8    9   21
```

And if you suspect there may be more than one minimum value per id, you can eschew the `which.min` function and use `which(x$time == min(x$time))`:

```
do.call('rbind', by(df, df$id, function(x) x[which(x$time == min(x$time)), ]))

#   id time var1 var2 var3
# 1  1    1    9   17   38
# 2  2   12    8    9   21
```

#### Data

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), 
time = c(2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 15L), 
var1 = c(4L, 8L, 9L, 8L, 25L), 
var2 = c(5L, 51L, 17L, 9L, 6L), 
var3 = c(6L, 7L, 38L, 21L, 23L)), 
.Names = c("id", "time", "var1", "var2", "var3"), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Answer (score 1):

**dplyr** using the function `slice`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    group_by(id) %>% 
    slice(which.min(time))
```

Output:

```
Source: local data frame [2 x 5]
Groups: id [2]

     id  time  var1  var2  var3
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int>
1     1     1     9    17    38
2     2    12     8     9    21
```

**sqldf**

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf('SELECT id, MIN(time) time, var1, var2, var3
                        FROM df 
                        GROUP BY id')
```

Output:

```
  id time var1 var2 var3
1  1    1    9   17   38
2  2   12    8    9   21
```